# Normal Distribution or Not

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

I have some net yield data (N=700) from a survey and I intend to carry out analysis to identify if there is any significant difference or relationships between the yield and the characteristics of the survey respondents (sex, education level etc). However, I am failing at the first hurdle i.e. I can't decide if the net yield data is normally distributed or not.

The descriptors below suggest that the data is only slightly positively skewed, but the data failed a Kolmogorov-Smirnova test (possibly due to the sample size?) and the histogram (attached) is not entirely perfect. I had decided that the data was not normally distributed. However, someone has suggest that the data is close enough to a normal distribution that it should really be treated as such. I was wondering what you think?

Statistic Description   Statistic   Std. Error
Mean                       5.37       0.124
95% Confidence Interval for Mean    Lower Bound 5.13
Upper Bound 5.62
5% Trimmed Mean            5.30
Median                     5.00
Variance                   10.926
Std. Deviation              3.305
Minimum                     0
Maximum                    12
Range                      12
Interquartile Range         5
Skewness                   0.237    0.092
Kurtosis                  -0.546    0.184

[image]

Many Thanks

Comment: It looks like the data are discrete, so they aren't even normal in theory.  It might be fine to treat the same as coming from a normal population, but for that we would need more information on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why do you need to know if the data are normal? What problem are you trying to solve and how does normality testing help you solve it?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The net yield was obtained by asking investors to select from a list of results (e.g less than 0%, 1%,2%,3%, 4% etc., through to >12%) during a survey. I then recoded the data into a new variable where <0% was treated as 0% and >12% was treated as 12%. I hope to carry out hypothesis testing to identify if the net yield obtained by investors is significantly different between groupings within the independent variables e.g. sex (male and female) and age group (25-35, 36-45 etc) etc. I am keen need to know if the net yield is normally distributed or not to allow me to i

Comment: There is clearly too many extreme cases (0 and 12) for a normal distribution

Comment: After you merge your accounts (visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), you will be able to edit your post and reply to comments.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be normal, but the transformation you've chosen breaks that assumption. There are way too fat tails in your distribution (left and right), because of the 0% and 12% data transformation.

I would suggest to evaluate the normality without such transformation. If the tails reduce to a "normal" level, then it would be suggested to consider that negative and above 12% data without any transformation at all.

However if the tail stay the same (in <0% and >12% areas, but not in 0% or 12%) then perhaps you shouldn't consider that extreme data, whenever possible.